# Ad is not displaying even though it getting response by using adwhirl

Tags: android, adwhirl

Hai I used basic code for adwhirl to display ads by using AdWhirl. I created new app in adwhirl site and I added that key in the activity.

```
adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this, "adwhirl_key");
```

I used one linear layout in xml for ad and for AdwhirlLayout as a child to this LinearLayout for ad, 
and declared parameters for this child in the activity. I added this childview to the LinearLayout instance(which i declared in main.xml) by calling `addView(adwhirlLayout instance);`

When I ran the app, I can see the logs which represents it receiving a response but I am unable to see the ad in the emulator.

Comment: Did you configure any ad networks for your app on the AdWhirl site?  Also, what exactly do your AdWhirl logs say?

Comment: yes u r right i forgot to add a new app in adhwhirl site ..my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, the process mentioned in the question is correct for integrating AdWhirl in Android.  You also need to register an app at [www.adwhirl.com](https://www.adwhirl.com) to get an `adwhirl_key` as well as configure the app in the UI with individual ad networks and percentages of requests for each network.